# Why can't I send files from Android to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth, file-transfer

With versions of Windows before 10, I could simply send files from any of my Android phones by selecting `Share > Bluetooth > [PC Name]` and at then the PC would show a dialog asking if I want to receive the file(s). After confirming, the transfer would begin.

With Windows 10, when trying to send a file from phone to PC, my phones quickly shows that the transfer was unsuccessful.

[image: Bluetooth file transfer unsuccessful]

Is there a different process now or is this something more complicated like driver issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that to receive bluetooth files in Windows 10, *first* right-click the Bluetooth icon in the taskbar and select "Receive a file".

[image: Windows 10 receive Bluetooth file menu]

You will then see the following:

[image: Windows 10 receive bluetooth file waiting for connection]

At this point, the file(s) can be sent from the phone and the computer will receive them.

Comment: In fact that was the same on any previous Windows with Microsoft Bluetooth drivers installed. It looks you have BlueSoleil or Toshiba on your previous Windows version. Those drivers has OBEX OPP server running by default.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - Interesting. I don't recall having to preemptively accept to receive a file in Windows, but maybe I'm just forgetting. Previously, I was using a very old Dell Latitude with XP, a Fujitsu Lifebook with vista, then a Dell XPS with Win 7, then a Lenovo Yoga with 8.1, another Latitude with Win 7, and now a Dell Precision with Win10.

Comment: This menu item always was there. However it depends on Bluetooth drivers. There are 2 well known: Microsoft (standard), BlueSoleil and Toshiba. On XP WidComm was also available. There are also few "extentions". So probably you had non-MS driver or one of extention that simple has OBEX server running. Any way, it was just for information. I did not want to say that you don't know something. Just for infor if someone will also look for the same question.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - Certainly helpful to know. I was just surprised. I was about to make a new question related to this along the lines of "How can I automatically receive bluetooth files in win10 without having to manually accept them beforehand?" Maybe that's not a good question to ask.

Comment: That is good question actually. I do not know why but I belive I saw the same sometime ago and there was some recomendation. From the other side there are lot of free software that can do it for you.